# jQuery Object Iteration

Tags: jquery, loops, object

I'm having a bit trouble iterating through objects in jquery.
I believe that on line 25 of the js file, holidays.date is not selecting what I intend to be selecting. Which is, for each object in the variable holidays, check to see if any of the date IS today's date. If it is than run the appends otherwise run the generic appends.

How can I fix that selector (holidays.date) to check those dates against today's date?

Thank you all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   var today = new Date(),
      month = today.getMonth(),
      months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
      date = today.getDate(),
      monthDay = months[month] + ' ' + date;

   var suHours = "We're Closed Today.",
      mHours = "9:00am to 5:00pm",
      tHours = "8:00am to 3:00pm",
      wHours = "9:00am to 5:00pm",
      thHours = "9:00am to 5:00pm",
      fHours = "9:00am to 7:00pm",
      sHours = "9:00am to 2:00pm";
   
   var holidays = [
         {date: 'May 10', hours: '8:00am to 12:00pm', message: 'Tuesday\'s Message - Merry Christmas!'}, 
         {date: 'May 11', hours: '9:00am to 1:00pm', message: 'Wednesday\'s Message - Happy New Years!'},
         {date: 'May 12', hours: '10:00am to 2:00pm', message: 'Thursday\'s Message - Happy Thanksgiving!'}, 
      ],
      generic = "Open Right Now!";

   function todayHoliday() {
      if ( monthDay == holidays.date ) {
         $.each( $(holidays), function() {
            $('.today-holiday-hours em').append(this.hours);
            $('.today-holiday-message em').append(this.message);
         });
      } else {
         $('.today-holiday-hours em').append('Generic Hours');
         $('.today-holiday-message em').append('Generic Message');
      }
   }
   todayHoliday();

});
```

```css
*, body, html {
   font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
   font-size: 15;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

body {
   margin: 20px;
}

h1, section {
   margin: 20px 0;
}

h3 {
   color: #aaa;
}

section p em {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>HoursJS Holiday Version</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
   <h1 id="title">HoursJS Plugin Holiday Version v: 0.0.1</h1>

   <hr>

<!-- Today is Holiday Hours & Message -->
   <section>
      <h3>Today is a Holiday:</h3>
      <p class="today-holiday-hours"><em></em></p>
      <p class="today-holiday-message"><em></em></p>
   </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not something you need jquery to loop over. Just do a `for in` loop or a `for of` loop over your `holidays` array

Comment: @winhowes  Not following you. Isn't the for in and for of essentially the same as each()? I don't know enough about the for in and for of to argue, but I thought they did the same as each.

Comment: Yeah they're similar, I'll post an answer using the .each to show you how it works with that. It just isn't necessary

Comment: They seem to be holding different values. Try printing out holiday.date and todays date

Comment: @Striker I think the issue is that holidays.date selector.  If I do holidays[0].date instead I start getting some results, but I'm being to specific. and not iterating through.

Comment: How about putting your check against this.date inside the each (holidays)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `.each` you don't need to "select" your holidays, just do this:

```
var matchFound = false;
$.each(holidays, function() {
    if ( monthDay == this.date ) {
        matchFound = true;
        $('.today-holiday-hours em').append(this.hours);
        $('.today-holiday-message em').append(this.message);
  } 
});
if (!matchFound) {
     $('.today-holiday-hours em').append('Generic Hours');
     $('.today-holiday-message em').append('Generic Message');
}
```

The selector (`$(something)`) is used to select elements in the DOM. In this case you already have an array so you can just iterate over it.

EDIT: I updated the function to put the if statement inside of the loop which I believe is the desired behavior. I've also moved the `else` statement outside of the loop based on the comments of desired behavior

Comment: I tried that, and it is still skipping over it and going straight to the generic (else) portion. I think the problems lays in the holidays.date. If I do holidays[0].date instead I start getting some results, but I'm being to specific.

Comment: @Sergio take a look at my edit, I think that will give you your desired output. You have the loop inside of your if statement, rather than the other way around. `holidays.date` is undefined because `holidays` is an array.

Comment: I actually had this before, but the problem is that since the else is inside the each, it will spit out 3 times the generic (else) portion. That's why I moved the each loop to go inside the if portion.

Comment: remove your if statement and use a boolean variable and set it in each ()

Comment: @Sergio is the desired behavior that the loop stop once it has found a match and otherwise print out the "Generic hours" bit?

Comment: @Sergio I updated my answer again to show you how to run the `if` statement multiple times but the `else` only once

Comment: Bingo! That worked perfectly. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var isHoliday = false;

$.each( $(holidays), function() {
     if ( monthDay == this.date ) 
    { 
        $('.today-holiday-hours em').append(this.hours); 
        $('.today-holiday-message em').append(this.message); });
        isHoliday = true;
    }
} 

if (!isHoliday )
{ 
    $('.today-holiday-hours em').append('Generic Hours');
    $('.today-holiday-message em').append('Generic Message'); 
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the answer winhowes provided above. Thank you so much for your help as well. I hate that I can't give you both credit for the correct answer. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the grep function

```
var xyz = $.grep(holidays, function (n) {
             return n.date === monthDay;
          });
```